# building a data.frame with variable names out of a vector

Tags: r

I am searching for an "automatic" way of naming variables in a data.frame, because I have a whole bunch of names.

So i thought it is the best way to put the names in a vector.
Lets say:

```
var_names <-  rep (c("a", "b"), 800 )   #of course they are all different in my vector
```

Now i have been running out of ideas: Here are some codes i tried. Maybe you get an idea of what i want.
As a first step it does not matter how many values are set into the variables, preferably NA.
"Assign+paste" creates the variablename, but i cannot grab it with my code anymore without using ist real name (remember that there are 800 different real names). But i need it, to put it together with the second/third... and to fill it with values.

badcode1

```
i=1
for (i in 1:800){
mtrx[,i]%>%
xxx <- assign((paste0(var_names[i]),NA) )  
}
```

badcode2

```
data_new <- data.frame(x, y)
attach(data_new)
(assign(paste0(var_names[i]),NA) )
detach(data_new)
```

badcode3

```
i=1
data_all =1   #zum definieren
for(i in 1:800){
x <- paste(var_names[i])
paste(var_names[i]) <- 1
View(paste(var_names[i]))     
(data_all <-  cbind(data_all, new_data) )
 }
```

Comment: `Maybe you get an idea of what i want.` Do you want to rename your columns in your dataframe by what's in `var_name`?

Comment: `colnames(df) <- var_names` this names `data.frame` columns

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful for us if you could illustrate the desired behavior. It's obvious not clear.

Comment: Thx Zelazny7. Thats it. Quite ease :-)